# How to pass build in arguments in R function?

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
f1<-function(a,b,c,d,e){
cbind(rnorm(a,mean=b,sd=1),
          rnorm(a,mean=b,sd=c),
        rbinom(a,d,e))
}
f1(10,8,2,2,0.8)
```

My question is how to use `...` in `f1()` to pass the common arguments in build in functions something like `rnorm` and `rbiom` in `f1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand your question, but if you're asking how to specify new defaults for functions, you can Curry them:

```
library(functional)
myrnorm <- Curry( rnorm, mean=b,sd=c )
myrnorm( a )
```

Alternatively, if you're asking how to pass in an unspecified set of arguments, that's easy:

```
f1<-function(a,...){
     rnorm(a,...)
}
f1(10,mean=2,sd=2)
```